# Check If File Exists, Download and Save File in J2ME

Tags: java-me, nokia, j2mepolish

I want to edit my question.

If file still not exist, download and save it, that my case.
To check if file exist, I've try by this code

```
private boolean isXmlFileExist(){
    try{
        FileConnection fCon = (FileConnection) Connector.open("file:///"+Resource.XML_PATH + "/" + Resource.XML_FILENAME, Connector.READ);
        return fCon.exists();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

In my resource class

```
public static final String XML_PATH = "/xml";
public static final String XML_FILENAME = "template.xml";
```

I have create 'xml' folder under res folder and i have put file 'template.xml' there. But this code always return false.
Whether we can not use the res folder? So, what is the correct path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files under `res` folder are always available because they are packaged with the class files. So, you do not need to check with `FileConnection` if they exist.
To access these files you can use [`Class.getResourceAsStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29).
For example:

```
private InputStream open (String fileName) {
  return getClass().getResourceAsStream(fileName);
}

// call it like this
open(Resource.XML_PATH + "/" + Resource.XML_FILENAME);
```

Comment: How about download xml file and save it under res folder? Do you have example or tutorial?

Comment: You can not save a file to the application package after it is installed on a device. You may save to the handset internal memory or sd card.

Comment: About download and save file, I have search tutorial about it, but still not find. My plan is to read the file content, create new file and write the content to the new file. Is this a good way?

Comment: Yes, it is. Start finding a place to right that file. Use FileSystemRegistry.listRoots() to see which are available.